# different environments (versions) for javac and java

Tags: java, variables, system, javac, environments

At the beginning I first installed JDK 7 on my **Windows 7** operating system . As usual I added the following path of my newly installed Java Development Kit to the system variable PATH.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

When running **javac** and **java** commands in **Command Prompt** they have both pointed to the same environment. So far so good.

---

For the purposes of Java application development at our enterprise I was forced to install an older instance of JDK thus installing JDK 6.

Below is the printout of my **PATH** system variable at the moment.

```
C:\dev\CollabNet\Subversion Client
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\
C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin
C:\Development\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin
C:\dev\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

But now I faced the situation where javac and java versions are different therefore pointing to different environments.

```
C:\Users\rokprodan>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_37

C:\Users\rokprodan>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

---

Does anybody have any suggestions and ideas for this situation? How could I achieve that both **javac** and **java** are pointing to **JDK 6** ?

I deep appreciate your advices and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installed public JRE, `java.exe` was put into `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.
But `javac` is not a part of JRE, so it is can be found only in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin`.

The solution is to place `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin` before `C:\WINDOWS\System32` in PATH environment variable.